# PHP Nesting loops. Mechanism?

Tags: php, for-loop, nested-loops, nested

I've this code and it works very well. All I want to know is that what is the mechanism of this code? Does the value of inner loop set to 1 every time? Like when the outer loop executes, a row is created and then the inner loop executes and counts to 11. The outer loop executes again. This time the value of outer loop is 2. Now my question is "Is the value of inner loop also 2 or it starts from 1? Thank you for your help :)

```
<?PHP
print "<table border = \"1\">";
for ( $y = 1 ; $y <= 12 ; $y++ ) {
print "<tr>";
    for ( $x = 1 ; $x <= 11 ; $x++ ) {
    print "<td>";
    print ( $x * $y );
    print "</td>";
    }
print "</tr>";
}
print "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The outer loop starts.

   - `$y` is set to 1
   - It will print `<tr>`
2. The inner loop starts.

   - `$x` is set to 1
   - It will print `<td>1</td>`
   - `$x` is set to 2
3. The inner loop goes on.

   - It will print `<td>2</td>`
   - `$x` is set to 3

...

4. The inner loop will stop.

   - `$x` was set to 12 so it will not match `$x <= 11` -> stop inner loop
   - Outer loop goes on and print `</tr>`
   - `$y` is set to 2
5. Outer loop goes on.

   - `$y` is 2
   - It will print `<tr>`
6. The inner loop starts.

   - `$x` is set to 1
   - It will print `<td>2</td>`
   - `$x` is set to 2

This is repeating until `$y > 12`. `$x` will be set to 1 everytime the inner loop starts.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it so easily :)